# How to extract points from point cloud from pcl::Indices

Tags: c++, pointers, point-cloud-library, pcl

Have this piece of code that is selecting the points I want to keep.

```
Eigen::Vector3f rodrigues(0,0,0);
Eigen::Vector3f boxCenter(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
Eigen::Vector3f box_size(0.9, 0.9 , 0.9);
            
pcl::BoxClipper3D<pcl::PointXYZRGB> boxClipper(rodrigues, boxCenter, box_size);
boxClipper.clipPointCloud3D (*this->cloud, windowPoints);
```

then I am trying to use `pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZRGB>`

```
pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZRGB> extract;
extract.setInputCloud (this->cloud);
extract.setIndices (XXX);
extract.filter (*inliers);
```

I am not able to compile the code because the method `setIndices ()` is taking as argument `pcl::IndicesPtr`

3 options :

- convert the `pcl::Indices` to `pcl::IndicesPtr`
- code a similar function myself
- use an other function that I don't know

Answer (score 0):

that does the tricks:
pcl::IndicesPtr idxPtr = boost::make_sharedpcl::Indices(obj);